# Missing rows after DataTable to csv conversion

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, export, export-to-csv

I'm using CsvHelper library to convert a csv file to another csv file with different structure. First I read the content of the csv file into a datatable and display on a DataGridView and everything works perfectly.

I have a problem exporting the content of the DataTable to the new csv file. For some reason some of the rows at the end of the DataTable aren't exported. I think it has something to do with the StreamWriter class but I can't find the cause.

I use Sharpdevelop.

```
//Read the original CSV file
void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

    if (result == DialogResult.OK) {
        StreamReader str = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);
        CsvReader csvReadFile = new CsvReader(str);

        dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("Time Stamp", typeof(DateTime));

        while (csvReadFile.Read()) {
            var row = dt.NewRow();
            foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns) {
                row[column.ColumnName] = csvReadFile.GetField(column.DataType, column.ColumnName);
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }
}
//Write the new CSV file
void SaveButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult result = saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
    if (result == DialogResult.OK) {
        StreamWriter stw = new StreamWriter(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
        CsvWriter csvWrite = new CsvWriter(stw);
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) {
            for (var i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++) {
                csvWrite.WriteField(row[i]);
            }
            csvWrite.NextRecord();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can't you just do `csvWrite.WriteRecords( dt.Rows );`?

Comment: If you put the writer in a `using` block it will `Dispose()` which will `Flush()` the buffer. This probably isn't quite having time to happen before your method exits. You should be careful to dispose anything that implements `IDisposable`, not just `StreamWriter`.

Comment: Where are you closing `stw`?

Comment: @Crowcoder It worked by using the "using" block. Thanks

Comment: @JohnG I wasn't and it was my mistake.